# c++ Intersect sets using std and save it in another set

Tags: c++, stl

I have two sets of int: `A = {1,3,5,7}` and `B = {2,4,5,7}`. How can I intersect them and save result in set A? So I want A to be equal to `{5,7}` after operations.

Comment: tried anything?

Comment: I found examples on stackoverflow, but they are not exactly what i need to do

Answer (score 2):

Using  [`std::set_intersection`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/) algorithm :

```
std::vector<int> A{1,3,5,7};
std::vector<int> B{2,4,5,7};

// Sort
std::sort(A.begin(), A.end());
std::sort(B.begin(), B.end());

std::vector<int> result;

std::set_intersection(A.begin(), A.end(),
                      B.begin(), B.end(),
                      std::back_inserter( result ));
```

Comment: @EdgarRokyan OP asked generically for a *set* of elements, not for `std::set`

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy with [std::set_intersection](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    std::vector<int> v2{        5,  7,  9,10};

    // Precondition: make sure they're sorted
    std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());

    std::vector<int> v_intersection;

    std::set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(),
                          v2.begin(), v2.end(),
                          std::back_inserter(v_intersection));

    for(int n : v_intersection)
        std::cout << n << ' '; // 5 7
}
```

<kbd>[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab6851a0df32a470)</kbd>